# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'

Tags: android

I'm not able to generate signed apk due to this error.
Some solutions I have tried but didn't solve the issue:
1- increasing heap memory in gradle.properties "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m"
2- Adding multiDexEnabled "true" in defaultconfig in build.gradle and compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
here is the complete error

```
Error:UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:       com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Mainfiest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:name=".app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value=" AIzaSyCJj4lgqkm35qQ2XDh-******* " />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>
</application>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 18
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile files('libs/volley.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
 }
```

Comment: Post your gradle.properties

Comment: Here it is org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m